# How to use mustache php to render unadulterated mustache js template with curly braces intact

Tags: mustache, mustache.php

I want to render a javascript mustache template in mustache php.  How do I render {{foo}} inside of script tags from php mustache with the {{foo}} curly braces being escaped, so that I can later render it as mustache.js template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I replaced all double curly braces {{var}} with angle brackets + percentage signs <%var%> in the php mustache template.  That way the delimiters persist after the php mustache rendering.  Then to render with mustache.js I added a couple of lines between the template call and render to set custom delimiters and parse template.

```
var template = $("#mytemplate").html();
var customTags = [ '<%', '%>' ];
Mustache.parse(template, customTags);
var output = Mustache.render(template, data);
```